# Error while building cordova project for IOS on ubuntu

Tags: ios, cordova

I trying build .ipa file using Cordova on ubuntu OS. I install required things like xcodebuild but it still gives me an error.

Error: xcodebuild was not found. Please install version 7.0.0 or greater from App Store

I created Cordova project using following command.

```
1. cordova create myAppIOSOne org.apache.cordova.myAppIOSOne myAppIOSOne

2. cd myAppIOSOne

3. cordova platform add ios

4. cordova build ios --device
```

Comment: You can't build ipa without a mac (or using phone gap ).

Comment: Is it possible by using phonegap?

Comment: https://build.phonegap.com this may help.

Comment: you can't build ipa without certificate ...